# Get a file's size through `IShellItem`

Tags: c++, windows, windows-shell

I've implemented a directory walking algorithm for the Windows Shell using `IShellItem`, `IShellFolder`, `IStorage`, `IStream`, etc. All is well and good. I can even walk inside shell namespace extensions (e.g. `.zip`) files.

However, I have problems extracting (regular) file sizes when files are being used by some other program with exclusive access.

AFAIK, there is nothing but the `STATSTG` structure that gives more information than the file's name. There are essentially 3 ways to get a hold of a `STATSTG` for a `IShellItem`:

1. Iterate using `IEnumSTATSTG` instead of `IEnumIDList`. Instead of invoking `IShellFolder::EnumObjects()`, get the `IStorage` for the folder and invoke `IStorage::EnumElements()`. You now get `STATSTG` structures directly.
2. Get the `IStorage` for the `IShellItem` and invoke `IStorage::Stat()`.
3. Get the `IStream` for the `IShellItem` and invoke `IStream::Stat()`.

I would really like to use #1 because it would give me all the information I need. However, I cannot get it to enumerate folder contents. I successfully extract the `IStorage` for the folder: it's own `Stat()` gives me the proper folder name. I successfully extract the `IEnumSTATSTG`, but the first call to `Next(1, &item, NULL)` returns `S_FALSE` and terminates the enumeration.

I would fallback to use #2 as it is still not so bad, but extracting the `IStorage` for regular disk files produces an error using both of `IShellItem::BindToHandler(0, BHID_Storage, ...)` and `IShellFolder::BindToStorage(child, ...)`.

I finally tried #3 although it just plains seems wrong and it succeeds as long as files are not being used with exclusive access by another program.

I've googled around a bit and found several code snippets that use approach #3.

**Question**: Can anyone explain how I'm supposed to get the file's `STATSTG` without using approach #3?

Should approach #1 work, or does the `IStorage` implementation for regular folders simply not produce listings? Should approach #2 work or is the `IStorage` implementation simply not implemented for regular files?

**Environment**: Windows Vista Ultimate 32-bit, Visual Studio 2008 Express. Using C++, no ATL, all custom COM wrappers (in-house, may be suitably modified assuming somwthing is wrong there).

Comment: Note that the file size of an open file is rather meaningless. Even if you found a function that returned it, the value could change by the very next instruction.

Comment: By that logic, checking the very existance of the file is meaningless. It could be deleted by another process before your next instruction is executed. I'm well aware of those problems, but implementing file browsing capabilities requires you to display outdated information :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried getting hold of the IShellItem2 interface, and then querying for the value of the PKEY_Size property?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that yet, mainly because it doesn't work for Windows XP (I go for compatibility with older systems when I can). Seems I don't have a choice, though. I'll check this out.

Comment: Any idea what header/version macro I need to get `PKEY_Size` constant to be defined? I keep googling but get lots of database related stuff. I guess `PKEY` is mistaken "primary key"...

Comment: Not at my desktop right now. I found it in one of the files in the Windows 7.0A\Include directory. You might need to install a newer Platform SDK.

Comment: Indeed, I grepped for it in the Platform SDK's Include folder and it didn't come out. I've settled for using `IShellFolder2::GetDetailsEx()` and it workds like a charm. It's compatible XP too!

Comment: @AndréCaron PROPERTYKEY

Answer (score 1):

Even with the accepted answer, it took some doing.

The first thing you need is the [**Windows Properties**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd561977(v=vs.85).aspx) reference. From there you have to know that you want to go into [**System.Size**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787566(v=vs.85).aspx). From there you get the two important pieces of information:

> ### System.Size
>
> The system-provided file system size of the item, in bytes.
>
> **shellPKey** = PKEY_Size
>   **typeInfo**
>             **type** = UInt64

Knowing that it's a `UInt64`, you can then get ahold of the [`IShellItem2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761130(v=vs.85).aspx) interface, in order to use one of the many property-getting methods:

```
//Get the IShellItem2 interface out of the IShellItem object
IShellItem2 si2 = shellItem as IShellItem2;

//Get the file fize (in bytes)
UInt64 fileSize;
si2.GetUInt64(PKEY_Size, ref fileSize);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post this answer!  I'm no longer in a position to validate its relevance though (I no longer work in that environment).  I hope it can still be useful for posterity.